# Two Pis communication via Bluetooth: Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, raspi-config

I am trying to connect two raspberry pi via Bluetooth these days. The Bluetooth I use is the Plugable USB Bluetooth. I want to set one pi to receive data sent from the other one so it can plot the data dynamically. However, I followed some instructions online and failed to make it. Here is my method:

1. Install everything needed including bluez, blueman, etc.
2. Modified /etc/bluetooth/rfcomm.conf like:

> ```
>   #
>     # RFCOMM configuration file.
>     #
>     rfcomm0 {
>      # Automatically bind the device at startup
>      bind yes;
>     # Bluetooth address of the device
>      device XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;
>     # RFCOMM channel for the connection
>      channel 1;
>     # Description of the connection
>      comment "XXX";
>     }
> ```

3. Type "rfcomm connect 0" on the pi that is going to send data. (I even try typing "rfcomm listen 0" on the receiving side.)

However, every time I only get "**Can't connect RFCOMM socket: Connection refused**". Can anyone help me with this problem? I managed to send data from PC to gumstix before using blueman in Ubuntu but this time is different. Thanks!

Comment: are you running as root? i.e. sudo <command>

Comment: Hello rob, I did run as root. I search it online and I guess it may have something to do with the pincodes file. However, I make one but it still does not work. Maybe I am missing some steps. I will try more after I finish my dues before spring break... If the problem can be solved before that, it will be fantastic. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this link is a present to connection 2 raspberry in Serial Port Profile in Bluetooth ;)
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=181682

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help). Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it is preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. In fact we're [enforcing this policy](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538): please edit so that the answer stands on its own should the link break in the future. If it is not edited within 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki.